# Is path of Ibrahim (AS) different from previous prophets?

Tags: prophet-ibrahim

Verse 6:161:

> Say, "Indeed, my Lord has guided me to a straight path - a correct
> religion - the **way of Abraham**, inclining toward truth. And he was not
> among those who associated others with Allah."

Why mention the "the way of Abraham?" I thought all the prophets followed the same path. Does this mean, for example, the path of Nuh (AS) is different from Abraham's (AS) path? Nuh (AS) message in the Quran is not different from that of any prophet.

Comment: [42:13](https://quran.com/42/13?translations=20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying to the image of the path, a path is a way. The way has several stations. Those stations are the Prophets .

From the station of Nuh (p.b.u.h), many other paths were used; we find the saga of Nuh in the polytheistic religion of the Akadians.

God showed the path to Ibrahim (p.h.u.h.). The path of Ishmael got lost through the time, and the children of Israel lost orientation in Egypt,

and God led Moses (p.b.u.h) and the prophets of Israel until Jesus. And again, some did not follow Him and some got astray

and God showed the path to Muhammad (p.b.u.h), who was a descendant of Ibrahim.

The  verse is directed to the audience of the tribes of Muhammad (p.b.u.h) whose ancestor path and religious path dissolved in the mean time and now was joint again.

It's probably for that reason that this and not an other prophet is mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Back then, the Quraysh Tribe had adopted the teachings of Prophet Abraham a.s and Prophet Ismail a.s which is Tawhid. They know Allah. However, they went astray.

> "And if indeed thou ask them who it is that sends down rain from the
> sky, and gives life therewith to the earth after its death, they will
> certainly reply, "(Allah)!" Say, "Praise be to Allah." But most of
> them understand not." (Translation by Yusuf Ali)
>
> Al-'Ankabut verse 63

> "Say: "Who is it that sustains you (in life) from the sky and from the
> earth? or who is it that has power over hearing and sight? And who is
> it that brings out the living from the dead and the dead from the
> living? and who is it that rules and regulates all affairs?" They will
> soon say, "(Allah)". Say, "will ye not then show piety (to Him)?"
> (Translation by Yusuf Ali)
>
> Yusuf verse 31

> "Abraham was an exemplary leader, devoted to God, a monotheist, and
> was not of the polytheists. Thankful for His blessings. He chose him,
> and guided him to a straight path. And We gave him goodness in this
> world, and in the Hereafter he will be among the righteous. Then We
> revealed to you ˹O Prophet, saying˺: “Follow the faith of Abraham, the
> upright, who was not one of the polytheists.” (Translation by Talal
> Itani and Dr Mustafa Khattab)
>
> An-Nahl verse 120-123

Back then, the Quraysh Tribe also fast

> "Quraish used to fast on the day of 'Ashura' in the Pre-Islamic
> period, and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) too, used to fast on that day. When
> he came to Medina, he fasted on that day and ordered others to fast,
> too. Later when the fasting of the month of Ramadan was prescribed, he
> gave up fasting on the day of 'Ashura' and it became optional for one
> to fast on it or not."
>
> [Bukhari 2002](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2002)

Back then, In the period of Ignorance (Jahiliyyah), i'tikaf was already known.

> "`Umar asked the Prophet (ﷺ) "I vowed in the Pre-Islamic period of
> ignorance to stay in I'tikaf for one night in Al-Masjid al-Haram." The
> Prophet (ﷺ) said to him, "Fulfill your vow.""
>
> [Bukhari 2032](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2032)

And Allah knows best.